# What poison am I?

Tags: word, cipher, knowledge

A very simple one:

> ----- .---- ----- .----  .---- ----- ----- .----  ----- .---- .---- -----  .---- .---- .---- .----  ----- .---- .---- .----  ----- .---- ----- .----  ----- ----- .---- -----  ----- ----- ----- -----  ----- .---- .---- -----  .---- ----- ----- -----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- ----- ----- .----  ----- .---- .---- .----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- .---- ----- .----  ----- ----- .---- -----  ----- ----- ----- -----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- ----- ----- .----  ----- .---- .---- .----  ----- ----- .---- .----  ----- .---- .---- .----  ----- ----- .---- .----  ----- ----- .---- -----  ----- ----- ----- -----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- ----- .---- .----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- ----- ----- .----  ----- .---- .---- -----  .---- .---- .---- -----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- ----- .---- .----  ----- .---- .---- -----  ----- .---- ----- .----  ----- .---- .---- .----  ----- ----- .---- -----

Hints will be provided as per day, however, considering the simplicity of this one, shouldn't be needed.

EDIT: Sorry about the confusion guys, but the translated line is a reference to something which has an author (this probably gives it away)

Comment: Probably morse. The numbers are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Cyanide

**Reasoning**
Your puzzle text translates to:

> You have ass cancer ([morse code](http://morsecode.scphillips.com/translator.html) + [ascii](http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp) decode)

Now searching for this on google, leads me to the following:

> [Cyanide and happiness](http://explosm.net/show/episode/38/the-man-who-could-sit-anywhere)

Comment: No, not quite, see my edit

Comment: We have a winner

Comment: Great one! I like Cyanide and Happiness

Answer (score 2):

The message reads

> You have ass cancer 
>    Initial message is morse code, which translates to a string of ascii characters in binary format.

So what poison are you?

> Not sure what poison causes ass cancer, and cancer itself is not a poison. Maybe the poison is the treatment... chemo.

After the update to the question, I'm going with:

> You are a toxic message

Comment: You're half way there

Comment: Why are my spoiler tags not working :(

Comment: You must satisfy the title of the puzzle

Comment: between your two lines of spoiler text add `>!` with three spaces

Comment: Maybe do a general search of the translated phrase on google and see what you get..